# c++ self written iterator - access violation reading from location 0x00000000 exception

Tags: c++

I have to write a program capable of storing movies for a university project. It was all fine until they decided that i had to write my own iterator to print out my heterogen collection in which the movies are stored (there are 3 different kind of movie class). I have absolutely no idea what the problem might be.

This is my class for the heterogen collection:

```
Class Katalogus {
    Film* F[100];
    int meret;
public:
    Katalogus() :meret(0) {}
    void add(Film* mit) {
        F[meret++] = mit;
    }
    void torol(int mit);
    void keres_int(int mit);
    void keres_str(string mit);
    void kiir(ostream& os); //This is the print method
    Film* beolvas(istream& is, string& line);
    ~Katalogus();
    class iterator;
    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(*this);
    }
    iterator end() {
        return iterator(*this, 100);
    }
    class iterator {
        Film *p, *pe;
    public:
        iterator():p(0),pe(0){}
        iterator(Katalogus& a, int ix=0):p(*(a.F+ix)),pe(*(a.F+100)){}
        iterator& operator++() {
            if (p != pe)++p;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator &i) {
            return (p != i.p);
        }
        Film& operator*() {
            if (p != pe) return *p;
            else throw out_of_range("Hibas indirekcio");
        }
    };

};
```

The kiir() function:

```
void Katalogus::kiir(ostream& os) {
    for (int i = 0; i < meret; ++i) {
        os << i + 1 << ". "; //just a number in every row
        F[i]->Print(os); //calling the print function of my stored movies
        os << endl;
    }
```

In my main() I've tried to test it with a short code:

```
Katalogus *DB = new Katalogus;
ifstream DataBase_in;
DataBase_in.open("Katalogus.txt");
string line;
while (getline(DataBase_in,line)){ //reading from file and adding it to the collection
    DB->add(DB->beolvas(DataBase_in, line)); //beolvas and add are both working functions
}
DataBase_in.close();

for (Katalogus::iterator it = DB->begin(); it != DB->end(); ++it) {
    (*it).Print(cout); //and this is where i get the exception
}
```

[This is the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1Un5.jpg)

My original kiir() function was working fine, but i have to replace it with something thet uses my iterator. If anyone could help with this I would really appriciate it! :)

Comment: Do you know which line of code in particular is throwing the exception?

Comment: Check to make sure `*it` isn't `nullptr` before calling `Print` on it.

Comment: From the text of the exception, it appears that the problem is that you are dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: Most likely *it is nullptr.

Comment: Please use English identifiers - Hungarian is nice, but not in code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `end` returns an iterator past the end of the array. So your iterator will iterate through unfilled elements of the array. Your original `for` loops only iterates through filled elements. Change your `end` function as follows:

```
iterator end() {
    return iterator(*this, meret);
}
```

This will refer to the first unfilled element in the array (or one past the end if the array is totally filled), causing your iterator to behave like your for loop.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but I've already tried this and it won't help.
Tried debugging, and I am still getting the same exception. Nothing changed. :/

Comment: @VrbovszkiBence What did your debugging reveal?

Comment: Well it turns out my operator++ was ruining everything. For some reason it did not increase my iterator properly and made it point to weird memory adresses.

Comment: @VrbovszkiBence Yeah, I see it now. You have an array of 100 pointers. Adding one to one of the pointers won't get you the next element in the array!